# Android proxy bypass local subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, android, bypass

I am deploying Android 4.4.3 devices to sites, and need a proxy for external internet access as it's a corporate environment. However, each site has a number of web pages hosted locally on the site server, meaning I need to bypass the proxy for the local subnet.

I have tried putting **local**, **.local**, and ***.local** in the bypass list on the device, and none of them work.

The only thing that appears to work is manually inputting the ip address of the local server. Unfortunately as these devices have the possibility of moving between sites, this is not an answer as I would need to enter over 100 individual IP addresses manually onto every device that we send out in order for them to function at every site, and being that the network settings will not allow me to save when I attempt this, it is not viable anyway.

Ideally I want a way to tell the Android device to bypass the proxy for any site that is on the current subnet, IE if it is connected to 10.61.1.0, then it should be able to access the websites on 10.61.1.100, and if it is then moved to 10.61.2.0 it can access 10.61.2.100 without a need to reconfigure.

I'm trying to develop a standard configuration for these devices, and this is causing me major difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always difficult to tell what is the accepted format of proxy exception entries, however I agree that .local or local should exclude any internal domains ending with that particular TLD. Are you positive that the internal servers that users need to access do in fact end .local?

I'm not sure about the feature set on 4.4.3 Android, however you may be able to make use of Proxy Auto configuration and use a PAC file to configure the devices. That way, you can add a rule which says, "if the destination website resolves to something in the 10.0.0.0/8 range (or whatever), go direct. Everything else, use the proxy.". You would then just need to host that PAC file somewhere and point all the devices proxy settings to it. In case you are unfamiliar with PAC files, [this is the place to go](http://findproxyforurl.com/).

Comment: Thanks, it appears that if I want to use a Proxy.PAC, I need at least Android 5.0 on the devices. Unfortunately I only have 4.4.3. and it would seem that the manufacturer has not released any further OS updates.

I fear that I may be out of luck on this occasion. thanks for the Help.

-MArk